# What is the equivalent of `UIViewController<MyProtocol>` of objc in swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I want to declare a function that accepts an UIViewController that adopts a particular protocol. How can I declare this in swift?

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    func subtitle() -> String
    func saveResults()
}

func setupViewController(controller: UIViewController<MyProtocol> ) { // ERROR here
    ...
}
```

**Why I want to do this:**
Because I have created a container view controller that has several children of different classes. What they have in common is `MyProtocol` and off-course the fact they inherit (directly or indirectly) `UIViewController`.

So one of my methods has one of this controllers as a parameter. I want to tell the compiler the most specific information possible: the object is an `UIViewController` and conforms to `MyProtocol`. How Can I declare this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't understand objective-c well but it looks than even in it you use generics to achieve what you are asking for (cant say that for sure because I have no idea about generics syntax in obj-c). In swift using generics your setupViewController function should like this:

```
func setupController<T:UIViewController where T:MyProtocol>(controller : T){

}
```

and this in functionality terms is completely equivalent with method from objective-c

Comment: Thank you, This is what I was looking for. BTW, there is no generics in objc, the `<` and `>` marks are for protocols only :) Thank you again.

Comment: I think this is the correct answer although it makes the compiler to crash. My project won't build anymore.

Comment: Where did you get error exactly ? I tried calling this function inside viewcontroller that adopt protocol `setupController(self)` then inside setupController I called a protocol method and it worked

Comment: @zellb i was wondering is there a swift compiler in taverna tirona ?

Comment: @TimurX. I was wondering also if there is any swift compiler available on Designers also or we can only find it in Sprigs in the Timbo table?