# How to express return type to be instance of a class which also confirms to a protocol in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, protocols

I would like to define the return type of a function to be an instance of `UIViewController` which also conforms to a certain protocol (for example `MyProtocol`). How is it possible?

```
protocol MyProtocol {
//I have also tried with protocol MyProtocol:class {
  func reload()
}

class MyParentViewController:UIViewController{
  /* Here I would like to express that it should return a
   * uiviewcontroller conforming to MyProtocol
   */
  func getChildViewController() -> MyProtocol {
    fatalError("implement in subclass")
  }
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    let child = getChildViewController()
    addChildViewController(child)
    child.reload()//from MyProtocol
  }
}
```

### EDIT

I found a workaround, which, I'm praying to Thor himself that you guys help me remove...

```
protocol MyProtocol {
  func reload()
  func returnSelf()->UIViewControlelr
}
...
override func viewDidLoad() {
  let child = getChildViewController()
  addChildViewController(child.returnSelf())
  child.reload()//from MyProtocol
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to create a custom abstract UIViewController subclass that implements your protocol:

```
protocol Reloadable{
   func reload()
}

class ReloadableViewController: UIViewController, Reloadable {   
   func reload() {
     fatalError("reload() should be implemented in subclasses")
   }   
}

class MyParentViewController: UIViewController{
   func getChildViewController() -> ReloadableViewController{
     //...your code goes here
   }
}
```

**EDIT:**
As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28744655/what-is-the-equivalent-of-uiviewcontrollermyprotocol-of-objc-in-swift) there is much better way to achieve this:

```
func getChildViewController<T:UIViewController where T:Reloadable>() -> T{
  let controller = ...
  return controller as T
}
```

Comment: Yes, but the reason i went with a protocol was that it can be applied to any of the existing uiviewcontroller subclasses (either my existing ones or from UIKit itself)

Comment: Sadly, but there is no way you can write something like this: `func a() -> UIViewController<Reloadable>`. Instead you should make all your own desired View Controllers to be subclasses of ReloadableViewController, and for desired UIKit View Controllers create subclasses in form `ReloadableTableViewController: UITableViewController, Reloadable{`

Comment: @NikitaArkhipov yes you can write `func a` by using generics. Check the possible duplicate comment above

Comment: Cool! That's what I didn't knew. So then yes, it is better then my solution, but mine will work as well )

Comment: @NikitaArkhipov I tried that, but when i assign the result of that function to a variable `let myVar = a()`, the compiler is not happy. can you give me a link to a documentation for the `<foo,bar>` syntax in Swift? I could not find myself

Comment: Yeah that's ok for compiler to have such a function but it is not happy when you are trying to call it. It also ok to have a function `func setChildViewController<T where T:UIViewController, T:Reloadable>(vc: T)`. That should be swift's compiler bug. The actual link to documentation of generics and `where` keyword: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GenericParametersAndArguments.html